# What should I use? A string or 15 integer fields?

Tags: database-design, performance, datatypes, query-performance

I am developing a student tracking program where I need to store 15 exam marks.

I can store the marks as a string and split them up when I need to, for purposes such as performing arithmetical operations. However, I need as much performance as possible.

Which is better?  A single string field, or 15 individual int fields?

Comment: "15 exam marks" - so like multiple choice of a single exam or the scores of 15 tests?

Comment: scores of 15 tests

Comment: Without more information about the type of database (traditional relational with indexing available?) and requirements for data access and usage patterns, it is difficult to say what design you should use and how it will perform.

Answer (score 27):

If you are already talking about splitting and computing, **don't** store this as an array.

Regardless of the relational theory and traditional normalization rules and dogma, it's simply a design which gives you MINIMAL flexibility.

Make each exam result a row.

I'm not trying to anticipate everything, but there are a very large number of things which this more granular (and, yes, normalized) and only ever so slightly more space expensive design facilitates which you may or may not need now and may or may not need in the future:

- Throwing out highest and lowest result?  You will have to slice up your array and sort it.
- Averaging?  You will have to slice it up and total it
- Analysis of exam result by exam across students?  You'll have to slice and pivot
- Sorting for counting (or instance British GCSEs, where it might be 7 As and 2Bs)?  You'll have to slice and sort

Note that all this slicing and sorting comes very cheaply in an indexed, normalized design.

Comment: Just what I was going to say  but you said it better! Storing mulitiple values in one string is one of the worst possible design choices for any database.

Comment: +1 Great further explanation from mine.  I tend to be *too* concise lol.

Answer (score 12):

For scores, performance-wise, the clear winner is storing it numerically something like this;

```
create table test_scores
(
  student_id int,
  test_id int,
  score int
);
```

Its easy to query, easy to update and add on, and super easy and fast to perform aggregates on.  Given the choice of "store this information as a string that I have to split up" or "store in a column"...the winner is almost always going to be "store in a column" for most use cases in a RDBMS.

Comment: If it's always the same set of 15 exams, it could well be that storing them denormalized (15 columns) is faster to process. A question, did you purposely propose an integer data type?

Comment: Additionally, for every 15 exams of 1 student your now storing 15 times a student ID and a test ID extra.

Comment: Seems like the queries and such would be simpler to write normalized though.  Just changing the test_id parameter vs a dynamic column name.  And it just more of a 'plan for the future'.  In terms of raw performance, 15 columns is probably marginally faster, but I don't imagine in a huge way.

Comment: As far as the choice of 'int' - it depends on the particular RDBMS choice.

Comment: Assume we take int as a data type. Which is 4 Bytes. in a 15 column design we would need 15x4=60 + 4 for the student ID = 64 Bytes. If we would store it in a 15 row design. we would need 12 Bytes per row. 4 for the studentID, 4 for the testID and 4 for the test result. times 15 rows = 180 bytes. That's almost 3 times as much. Potentially a huge difference.

Comment: Empirical test coming.

Comment: fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f7343/10

Comment: I think *rfusca*'s answer is the best one. Saving the the marks of all different exams in form of string with individual marks entry separated by comma or some other delimiter is also an option, but you have to decode it at the code level. Length of string will be variable.

Comment: @EdwardDortland it'll always be 15 until it isn't.

Comment: @EdwardDortland: The calculations are fine. Now, can you do them for the indices you may need?

Comment: @EdwardDortland another thing to consider - how would you handle students re-sitting exams in your schema?

Comment: @therefromhere as discussed with Rfusca, I'm not taking any logical design, application refactoring points into consideration. I simple answering with in the scope of the very vaguely formed question. From a logically point of view, the OP basically asked what is faster Storing it in first norm violation or second norm violation. In that case, second is faster.  However after a nice chat with rfusca and vriends, I accept it's debatable weither answer just the question is in the best interest of the OP. For that, I stand corrected. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

as long as you use tiny int (0 to 255) using a char(15) or 15 tinyint is the same (size wise). So then from a performance perspective, go for the 15 tinyints since you save on the extraction and string handling.

**UPDATE**

if the marks are double digits, you'll need CHAR(30) and that is twice the size of 15 times a tinyint.

Comment: Given this extremely simple design, if there's an institution on this planet that has enough students sitting 15 exams (with marks) to cause performance problems in a modern RDBMS, I'll cry myself to sleep tonight.

Comment: If the marks are double digits? But tiny int covers scores from 0 to 255, or -127 to 127 depending on how you prefer to count. So since scores rarely go negative, that gives 250+ points for one exam, and most exams are scored on a 0-100% scale. I think tinyint is absolutely useful here.

Comment: Yes we agree, I was simple stating that with double digit marks as opossed to single digit marks it becomes even worse to store it as char. Since then you would need char(30) instead of char(15). While double digit or not, 15 tiny ints will always be just 15 bytes.

Comment: -1 because this answer recommends the fields per row design that is far inferior to the storing of each exam result in its own row as proposed by the other posts